# Making a weighted graph chordal using algebraic topology

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology

This is just a question that I've been thinking about recently and I am curious to know more about the connection between graph theory and topology in general, but this idea has been on my mind for a few weeks that probably using deformation retractions or other topological tools, we should be able to make a graph chordal.

I searched around and found a few papers that were interesting such as [this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.11946.pdf), but couldn't find anything exactly related to what I wanted.

I was wondering if anyone here has any ideas here.

Imo, it would be really interesting if we could turn a graph into a topological space, and using those topological tools we could make a weighted graph chordal by retracting the minimum edges with some topological techniques with less timely-expensive algorithms.

I'd appreciate any help and comments.

Thanks.

Comment: What does it even mean to "make" a graph chordal? A graph is either chordal or it isn't. You can always be inspired by a non-chordal graph $G$ to make a new, chordal graph $H$, but the question is then whether looking at $H$ tells us anything useful about $G$.

Comment: You're right, my question is a little confusing. What I mean is that we have a weighted graph G, and we want to use edge contraction to get a chordal graph.